# Correct generation of words in python

Tags: python, loops, scalability

I think the intentions of this code are clear. I want to have in X all possible input words, with each digit being an element in a list. The following code works for 4 digits, but it gets unsustainable for bigger words. How can I make it more scalable? Let's assume I want the words of n digits instead of four.

```
d = [0,1]
X = [[x1,x2,x3,x4] for x1 in d for x2 in d for x3 in d for x4 in d]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for that:

```
from itertools import product

d = [0,1]
x = [list(t) for t in product(d,repeat=4)]
```

This gives:

```
>>> x
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

And by modifying `repeat=` to for instance `5` you get all possible 5-digit lists.

In case you do not need lists - the elements are not supposed to be altered - tuples can be used, and in that case you can drop the `list(..)` construction:

```
# list of tuples

from itertools import product

d = [0,1]
x = list(product(d,repeat=4))
```

This generates:

```
>>> x
[(0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0, 1), (0, 1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1, 1), (1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0, 0), (1, 1, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1, 1)]
```

Note that `product(..)` itself **is a generator**: it generates the elements **lazily**. This can be useful if the number of resulting elements will be huge and you can process them *one-at-a-time*. In that case you thus better do not construct a list. You can for instance use:

```
for tup in product(d,repeat=4):
    print(tup)
```

To print all tuples. Although the effect would be the same as with a `for tup in x:`, now the memory usage *can* be lower (it depends on the implementation of the garbage collector in the interpreter): since not all tuples have to be in memory at the *same time*. The next tuple the generator emit can possibly *reuse* the memory the previous tuple took since that place is now vacant (at least given you do not store the tuples in a list, etc.)

Comment: The generator thing is interesting. Would something like `[0,0,1,1] in product(d,repeat=4)` work then?

Comment: @DaniMedina: I wrote a small code fragment to demonstrate a possible usage of the generator.